# Why is my model not training correctly?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I am new to using neural networks so apologies if this is a dumb question. However, I have tried to figure it out for over a day now and have made no progress, so I've come to ask for help.

I am creating an LSTM model that seeks to generate music. I have pre-processed the data into the following format: [image]

where 64 is the batch size, and 50 is the sequence length. The goal is to input a sequence into the model, and have it predict the following note as output, and so the input sequence is a tensor of notes, and the target is the note that comes after. My LSTM model is built as follows:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(
    256,
    input_shape=(SEQ_LENGTH, 1),
    return_sequences=True
))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(512, return_sequences=True))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(VOCAB_SIZE))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

When training, the model starts at a loss of about 5.8 and quickly descends to below 0.1 in the first epoch. In the following epochs, the loss goes to incredibly low values, such as 4.6e-06, and only gets lower. This cannot be correct, right? I've tried other loss functions such as MSE and categorical cross-entropy, however they give similarly bizarre results - MSE stays the same the whole time and categorical cross-entropy increases to values in the thousands. I'm pretty sure spare cross-entropy is the correct loss function as I am not using one-hot vectors, but it doesn't seem like it is -  or maybe there is some issue with my input data?

Obviously, I am missing something, but I just don't know what it is that I'm doing incorrectly. Could anyone help me with this? If you need any more information about the model etc., please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any other reason to believe that something is wrong besides training loss dropping very fast..? If no, this doesn't sound like a problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I don't have any particular reason to believe anything else is wrong - as far as I'm aware I've done everything correctly. I was just concerned over the extremely low values of loss - I have never seen values such as these: https://i.imgur.com/1oZDYnG.png on other example loss graphs online - they are all around the 0.01 mark at lowest. Are my concerns over these values unfounded? Again, thank you for the answer